# How do I make one section disappear when another is clicked? In PHP

Tags: php, html

The output of the code below looks like:

```
Current Discounts for: *category name*
<5 book cover images that link to books>
<5 book cover images that link to books>

MORE CURRENT DISCOUNTS image link

PAST Discounts for: *category name*
<5 book cover images that link to books>
<5 book cover images that link to books>

MORE PAST DISCOUNTS image link
```

QUESTION: "I have current discount books and past discount books being displayed (incrementally from $Bookarray and $Bookoldarray. When a user clicks on MORE PAST DISCOUNTS, I want CURRENT DISCOUNTS to disappear, and PAST DISCOUNTS be the only section visible on page. How do you do this in PHP? In Visual Basic I would have made an increment variable and incremented it if MORE CURRENT DISCOUNTS was pressed, then say IF incvariable is > 1 run both section, else just run second section."

HERE IS THE CODE

```
<p>Current Discounts for: <?php echo $whatcategory ?></p>

<?php

$currentp = isset($_GET['currentp']) ? $_GET['currentp'] : 1; 

for($i = 0; $i < $currentp; $i++) 
next($Bookarray); 

if(current($Bookarray) === false){ 
reset($Bookarray); 
$i = 0; 
} 

$currentIndex = current($Bookarray); 

?> 


<?=current($Bookarray)?></br><img src="images/bookdiv.jpg" width="547" height="20" /></br>
<a href="?currentp=<?=$i+1?>"><img src="images/current.jpg" width="215" height="32" /></a></br>


<p>Old Discounts for: ><?php echo $whatcategory ?></p>

<?php

$oldp = isset($_GET['oldp']) ? $_GET['oldp'] : 1; 
for($i = 0; $i < $oldp; $i++) 
next($Bookoldarray); 
if(current($Bookoldarray) === false){ 
reset($Bookoldarray); 
$i = 0; 
} 

$currentIndex = current($Bookoldarray); 

?> 


<?=current($Bookoldarray)?></br><img src="images/bookdiv.jpg" width="547" height="20" /></br>
<a href="?oldp=<?=$i+1?>"><img src="images/old.jpg" width="190" height="32" /></a>
```

Comment: Since 100% of this happens on the CLIENT, it has nothing to do with PHP, which runs on the SERVER. Show your HTML output, not your PHP server code.

Comment: you will need javascript to make your page interactive

Comment: You can do this without javascript, it just means there will be a page reload. Unfortunately I don't quite understand the code in question, but it should be straight-forward. Just make a link that goes to a URL like `?view=past_discounts` then show content based on `$_GET['view']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are reloading the page and going back to PHP to get the next set of discounts to display, you can just put a php `if` block around the entire "Current Discounts" section and checking if the 'oldp' variable has been set.

```
<?php
// Check if user clicked on Past Discounts
if(!isset($_GET['oldp']) {
?>

<p>Current Discounts for: <?php echo $whatcategory ?></p>

<?php
    $currentp = isset($_GET['currentp']) ? $_GET['currentp'] : 1; 
    for($i = 0; $i < $currentp; $i++) 
        next($Bookarray); 

    if(current($Bookarray) === false){ 
        reset($Bookarray); 
        $i = 0; 
    } 

    $currentIndex = current($Bookarray); 
?> 

<?=current($Bookarray)?></br><img src="images/bookdiv.jpg" width="547" height="20" /></br>
<a href="?currentp=<?=$i+1?>"><img src="images/current.jpg" width="215" height="32" /></a></br>

<?php
}
// End if (Hide current discounts if past discounts clicked)
?>

<p>Old Discounts for: ><?php echo $whatcategory ?></p>
```